# Making 700 API calls together and merging the data using AWS Lambda

Tags: python, node.js, rest, api, aws-lambda

I have a task wherein I have to make 700 REST API calls. I have used a loop, but the run time of the loop is more than the timeout of AWS Lambda service. Is there any way I can make the calls concurrently and merge the results. I am using node JS, but a solution in python is also welcome

Here is a sample of the code I am running now:

```
HitBTCData = {}
for item in exchanges:
    itemlist = item.split('-')
    response = requests.get('https://min- 
    api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute? 
    fsym='+itemlist[0]+'&tsym='+itemlist[1]+'&limit=2000&aggregate=1
    &e=HitBTC').json()

    if itemlist[0]+itemlist[1] not in HitBTCData:
        HitBTCData[itemlist[0]+itemlist[1]] = []
        HitBTCData[itemlist[0]+itemlist[1]].append(response['Data'])

    while response['Type'] != 1:
        time = response['TimeFrom']
        response = requests.get('https://min- 
        api.cryptocompare.com/data/histominute? 
        fsym='+itemlist[0]+'&tsym='+itemlist[1]+
       '&limit=2000&aggregate=1&toTs='+str(time)+'&e=HitBTC').json()

        if response['Type'] != 1:
          HitBTCData[itemlist[0]+itemlist[1]]
          .append(response['Data'])

    HitBTCData[itemlist[0]+itemlist[1]] = 
    HitBTCData[itemlist[0]+itemlist[1]][::-1]
```

Comment: Hi, can you edit the question and provide some code that you have tried?

Comment: I have to fetch market data for 700 pairs of crypto-currencies. I am using a single loop to fetch the data, thus making 700 sequential calls. This takes up more than 8 minutes to finish. AWS Lambda times out at 5 minutes. How to come up with a faster solution?

Comment: Can we see your code? We can't help you otherwise.

Comment: Yeah I edited the question

Comment: umm... you are making 2000 get requests in every invocation?

Comment: Why did you say you are using NodeJS but you included a sample of Python code? In any event you need to make the calls asynchronously, so you should pick a programming language and then look up how to make asynchronous calls in that language.

Comment: Yes, 2000 is the limit they provide

Answer (score 0):

Use a loop in Node.js and the calls will run concurrently, but to make sure all of your calls are processed before exiting the lambda, you need to have some form of counter to make sure all of the queries have ended.

example:

```
var request = require('request');

var results = [];
var runningQueries = 0;
exchanges.forEach(function (item) {
  ++runningQueries;
  callAPI (item, function (err, data) { 
    if (err) {
      results.push(err)
      --runningQueries;
    } else {
      results.push(data)
      --runningQueries;
    }
    if (runningQueries == 0) {
      // all call results have been collated, so do something
    }
  })
})
```

You'll need to build your own callAPI function. Also, I'm being a bit lazy with what I'm pushing to the array here, but it's just to give you a framework.

Answer (score 0):

You could very easily do this with `Promise.all()`:

```
const urls = [...];

const requestFunction = async (url) => {
    // all your ifs go here
    let data = await request(url);
    // transform/sanitize your data
    return data;
}

const allResults = await Promise.all(urls.map(requestFunction));
// you now have an array of results
```

The only downside to `Promise.all()` is that if any of the promises rejects, everything fails. So I would suggest catching errors and resolving with `null` or something similar.

You could do a `for` loop to generate your array of URLs, `new Array(700).map(...)`, or since it looks like you already have some kind of array, just `.map()` that directly and do more transforms inside the request function.